# CDN Cloudfront closes connection after message from beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have an app on beanstalk which works as it should. Recently I have been using Cloudfront (CDN) to make use of HTTPS and to serve my clients a proper URL. My app sends data in small amounts to the browser, therefore it takes a long time for the browser to receive the file. This is no problem when I run it from beanstalk but when visiting app trough Cloudfront connection is closed before all the data is sends.

I check my beanstalk health logs and it seem this happens right after I get this message: `100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (6.0 requests/min) to determine application health`

I could conclude that my app makes the server crash somehow but than again the app works excellent from beanstalk url where I also get the error message.

So my question: why does it run perfectly in Beanstalk but Cloudfront drops connection after the error message?

ps. this is not related to Cloudfront timeout or browser timeout.

Comment: Could it be that Cloudfront drops connection for security reason because of the HTTP 4xx (send by agent)

Comment: *"ps. this is not related to Cloudfront timeout"*  How have you proven this?  CloudFront doesn't wait around.  The timeout is 30 seconds.  Also: 4XX covers a lot of errors.  What specific error code actually gets logged by the application, and what error code is returned to the browser?  Are you using chunked transfer encoding in your application or just writing octets to the wire and hoping for the best?  What shows in the CloudFront log?

Comment: It turns out it is a timeout problem after all. Not sure yet but I think I misconfiguted DB settings, making to many calls. Thanks for your time